# Is it possible to send a notification from a google home device to a google assistant device with a screen?

Tags: actions-on-google

I ask the user for a review at the end of the conversation using a basicCard. 
It is not possible on a device with no screen or web browser so essentially I can only ask for reviews when my action is used on an android or iOS device.
So, is it possible to send a notification from the user's non screen device to his phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [multi-surface conversations](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/surface-capabilities#multi-surface_conversations), which will allow you to send a notification from a speaker to a phone to continue the conversation with the same session.